# How can I search for a string in a txt file?

Tags: nsis

Is there some way that I can search in a `example.txt` file for a string `example`?

I tried `Fileread` and `Fileseek` but it is not working yet... later I'd like to write to the file, that's why I use `FileOpen` with the `a` append attribute:

```
FileOpen $4 "$SYSDIR\drivers\etc\hosts" a
FileSeek $4 0 SET
FileRead $4 $1
${If} $1 != "example"
Strcmp $1 "example" end 0
```

Or can I walk through the file with `While`? But when does the file end?

### Update

```
!define IP_AND_DISPATCHER "30.0.0.0 dispatcher"
    FileOpen $0 "$SYSDIR\drivers\etc\hosts" a
loop:

   FileRead $0 $2
   IfErrors done
   Messagebox MB_OK "$2"
      StrCmp $2 "${IP_AND_DISPATCHER}$\r$\n" 0 loop
MessageBox MB_OK "$${IP_AND_DISPATCHER} found"
FileClose $2     ;close file
Quit

done:
    FileSeek $0 0 END
    FileWrite $0 "$\r$\n" ; new line
    FileWrite $0 "${IP_AND_DISPATCHER}" ;write ip and dispatcher
    FileWrite $0 "$\r$\n" ; extra line
 FileClose $0     ;close file
```

Now its working, but is there a way to not write the `30.0.0.0 dispatcher` so not the entire line... just, for example, the `dispatcher` word?

Comment: There are 2 ways to show code in a question: either indent a block code by at least 4 spaces or 1 tabulation, or use the dedicated back quote

Answer (score 3):

The NSIS wiki contains several examples for [text files manipulations](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category:Text_Files_Manipulation_Functions), with

- 2 examples for searching in a file [with](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Search_for_text_in_file) or [without](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Search_in_file_(taking_into_consideration_of_the_comment_delimiters)) comments defining function for delegating the tedious string manipulations based on `StrCmp`
- and another example for [writing](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_write_text_to_file) in a file, while there is another for [replacing text](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/More_advanced_replace_text_in_file)

You can base your own work on these examples.

Comment: I agreed replacing text is the easiest way to do that.